# How lssas.exe store users hash?

Tags: active-directory

Does lssas.exe store local and domain account user hashs and if lssas.exe store hash on memory, when I reboot computer  attacker could not get older login user hashs right? But when I dump lssas.exe with crackmapexe I got domain admin hash but I was logged in 20 days ago and I rebooted machine a few days ago. How that happens.
windows only store hash from sam, lssas.exe and ntds.dit? Is there another place to store it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Kerberos, NTLM, and Credential Manager isolate secrets by using
> Virtualization-based security (VBS). Previous versions of Windows
> stored secrets in its process memory, in the Local Security Authority
> (LSA) process lsass.exe. With Credential Guard enabled, the LSA
> process in the operating system talks to a component called the
> isolated LSA process that stores and protects those secrets,
> LSAIso.exe. Data stored by the isolated LSA process is protected using
> VBS and isn't accessible to the rest of the operating system. LSA uses
> remote procedure calls to communicate with the isolated LSA process.
>
> For security reasons, the isolated LSA process doesn't host any device
> drivers. Instead, it only hosts a small subset of operating system
> binaries that are needed for security and nothing else. All the
> binaries are signed with a certificate that VBS trusts, and the
> signatures are validated before launching the file in the protected
> environment.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/credential-guard/how-it-works